# Calling a Function error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, declaration

**UPDATE:**  Okay, thanks everyone! My textbook says that the function prototype requires the functions to be declared in the parenthesis, and the examples shown look slightly different from the code itself in the function header and function body, so.. I went with what it was showing me. I corrected it with the suggestion of leaving the prototype's parenthesis empty and it worked.

For the record, I genuinely hate these textbooks... Thank y'all again for your help!

**OP:**
I'm getting this error:

> C2660 'getLetter': function does not take 0 arguments.

The code is this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

char getLetter(char letter);

int main()
{
    char firstLetter = getLetter();
        cout << firstLetter;
    return 0;
}   //end of main function

char getLetter()
{
    char letter = ' ';
    cout << "Enter a character: ";
    cin >> letter;
    return letter;
}   // end of getLetter function
```

My code looks like the example given in the book, but none of the examples use the "char" function, they all use double or int; not sure if that matters.  The error (on line 12, bottom of the main function) is also the code written by my instructor, not I, which makes it even more confusing for me.  I'm having trouble grasping this lesson and need a second viewpoint.

Comment: Change the declaration `char getLetter(char letter);` to `char getLetter();`, to make its signature match the definition.

Comment: Read the error. Look at your code. There are 3 lines with `getLetter` on them. Do they all look the same?

Comment: @songyuanyao Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function declaration statement accepts a `char`:

```
char getLetter(char letter);
```

If you want to change it so that it no longer requires a char as a parameter, just use this:

```
char getLetter();
```

**WHY:**

Your function signatures *must* be the same as your function definitions and your function calls.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Way better explanation than what my textbook was showing me.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Before the call of the function in the following code snippet

```
int main()
{
    char firstLetter = getLetter();
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
    //...
```

you declared the name `getLetter` as a function that has one parameter

```
char getLetter(char letter);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^

int main()

//...
```

The compiler does not see yet another function declaration that you placed after main.

```
char getLetter()
{
    char letter = ' ';
    cout << "Enter a character: ";
    cin >> letter;
    return letter;
}   // end of getLetter function
```

So the compiler issues an error.

It is evident that you were not going to overload the function and made a typo. Remove the parameter declaration in the function declaration before main.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Vlad.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration does not match the function definition.

Comment: Thank you for your help.